# Monitor process and sending email on thresold memory usage

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell.
I have to monitor one process and based on memory usage sending the email-notification.I am fine with function of sending email.that is working fine.but calculating memory usage is problem form me i am not able to convert from system.object to Intiger.My poewershell script is test.ps1 is as below:-

```
#$p = get-process chrome | select @{l="Private Memory (MB)"; e={$_.privatememorysize / 1mb}}


$f= [Math]::Round($p, 2) 
if($t -lt 40)
{ send email}
```

even though I tried with this $t=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='Powershell.exe'" | select workingSetSize | fl.

But it did not work fine for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, use `Set-StrictMode -version 2.0` to catch the uninitialized variable `$p`:

```
#$p = get-process chrome | select @{l="Private Memory (MB)"; e={$_.privatememorysize / 1mb}}
PS C:\> $f= [Math]::Round($p, 2)
The variable '$p' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

That's because the part where `$p` is initialized *is commented*:
**`#`**`$p = get-process`. Note the hash char.

`Get-Process` will return an object that doesn't need much mucking around.

```
PS C:\> $p = get-process powershell
PS C:\> [Math]::Round($p.privatememorysize/1mb, 2)
67,4
```